# IOS Facebook SDK, fetch user info

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-sdk-4.0

is it possible, using the Facebook SDK, to get the user info from his user id? An important note is that the user would have approved the application and its permissions before the app make the request.
If it is possible, what is the right way to achieve this? I am trying using this code:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/100007046299250"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                      }];
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Error for request to endpoint '/100007046299250': An open FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After login authentication, you can get details from active FBSession like below

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
       NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
       NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSString *firstName = user.first_name;
             NSString *lastName = user.last_name;
             NSString *facebookId = user.id;
             NSString *email = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
             NSString *imageUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", facebookId];
         }
     }];
}
```